# Problems trying to train a custom object detection model using Tensorflow2 and Google Colab

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api, custom-training

I've been trying to use tensorflow2 and transferlearning to find a certain object. This is the code I've got so far, the first steps work without any problem but when I try to trin the model (the last command), I have some errors (AttributeError)but I don't know how to solve them, I think it has to do with the .tfrecord files providing the images but I'm not completly sure. It's my first time working with something like this.
[This is the link to my google colab proyect:](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1thawQ43-zB_onU0D2u_QEyHR_YiwnRAz?usp=sharing)

The code that is giving me the errors:

```
num_classes = 1
batch_size = 36
num_steps = 7500
num_eval_steps = 1000

train_record_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/train.tfrecord'
test_record_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/test.tfrecord'
model_dir = '/content/training/'
labelmap_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/labels.txt'

pipeline_config_path = '/content/mobilenet_v2.config'
fine_tune_checkpoint = '/content/mobilenet_v2/mobilenet_v2.ckpt-1'
import re

with open(pipeline_config_path) as f:
    config = f.read()

with open(pipeline_config_path, 'w') as f:

  # Set labelmap path
  config = re.sub('label_map_path: ".*?"',
             'label_map_path: "{}"'.format(labelmap_path), config)

  # Set fine_tune_checkpoint path
  config = re.sub('fine_tune_checkpoint: ".*?"',
                  'fine_tune_checkpoint: "{}"'.format(fine_tune_checkpoint), config)

  # Set train tf-record file path
  config = re.sub('(input_path: ".*?)(PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED/train)(.*?")',
                  'input_path: "{}"'.format(train_record_path), config)

  # Set test tf-record file path
  config = re.sub('(input_path: ".*?)(PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED/val)(.*?")',
                  'input_path: "{}"'.format(test_record_path), config)

  # Set number of classes.
  config = re.sub('num_classes: [0-9]+',
                  'num_classes: {}'.format(num_classes), config)

  # Set batch size
  config = re.sub('batch_size: [0-9]+',
                  'batch_size: {}'.format(batch_size), config)

  # Set training steps
  config = re.sub('num_steps: [0-9]+',
                  'num_steps: {}'.format(num_steps), config)

  f.write(config) 
!python /content/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py \
--pipeline_config_path={pipeline_config_path} \
--model_dir={model_dir} \
--alsologtostderr \
--num_train_steps={num_steps} \
--sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=1 \
--num_eval_steps={num_eval_steps}
```

And the errors:

```
AttributeError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/object_detection/data_decoders/tf_example_decoder.py", line 556, in decode  *
        tensors = decoder.decode(serialized_example, items=keys)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tf_slim/data/tfexample_decoder.py", line 722, in decode  *
        outputs.append(handler.tensors_to_item(keys_to_tensors))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tf_slim/data/tfexample_decoder.py", line 405, in tensors_to_item  *
        return self._decode(image_buffer, image_format)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tf_slim/data/tfexample_decoder.py", line 453, in _decode  *
        image = control_flow_ops.case(

    AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.ops.control_flow_ops' has no attribute 'case'
```

Comment: Looks like you have a version mismatch. Maybe you can use an older tensorflow as suggested here. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/11099